# How to configure simpleclip in emacs terminal mode to copy-paste interchangeably with OS?

Tags: emacs, terminal

I'm using `emacs -nw` (Emacs 24.5, Ubuntu 16.04). And I found that the default emacs `M-w` `C-y` keys don't work interchangeably with the operating system.

After some research, it seems that the most comprehensive solution is to use simpleclip. [EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CopyAndPaste) says that

> simpleclip
>
> You can use https://github.com/rolandwalker/simpleclip which ALWAYS
>   works.

But looking into its usage guide above, `simpleclip` makes use of a set of keys that are *completely different* from the default `M-w` `C-y` or the OS `Ctrl-Shift-c`, `Ctrl-Shift-v` for copy-paste

> ;; Press super-c to copy without affecting the kill ring.
>
> ;; Press super-x or super-v to cut or paste.

I don't really want to use `super` key a lot with my PC keyboards, and don't want to remember (or persuade others to remember) yet another set of copy-paste keys.

For the GUI emacs, I can copy something in emacs and paste it into another terminal without any configuration. Mostly, I don't feel that Emacs is any different from `gedit` except that the emacs copy-paste keys `M-w` `C-y` can be used *in addition*.

In the terminal mode, most of it breaks down. If I use OS copy (`Ctrl-Shift-c`), one line in emacs can be copied into two or more lines in a target terminal because the line is too long. contents copied using `M-w` simply do not paste into other programs, even though I tried to set certain variables following other SO questions, e.g.:

```
(setq x-select-enable-clipboard t)
```

I'm not very familiar with elisp. My question:

*How can I customize or configure `simpleclip` so that copy-paste in `emacs -nw` is exactly the same as copy-paste in the OS?*

Other related SO questions:

[How to copy text from Emacs to another application on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64360/)

[emacs terminal mode: how to copy and paste efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27764059)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use the `xclip` package, which you can install from GNU ELPA (i.e. via `M-x package-list-packages`).  It requires installation of the `xclip` utility under X11 (e.g. via `aptitude install xclip`) and uses the `pbcopy/pbpaste` under macOS.